# cast to UNSIGNED from a negative number

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(-6 AS UNSIGNEd);
+----------------------+
| CAST(-6 AS UNSIGNEd) |
+----------------------+
| 18446744073709551610 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST(6 AS UNSIGNEd);
+---------------------+
| CAST(6 AS UNSIGNEd) |
+---------------------+
|                   6 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST(6 AS CHAR)
    -> ;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    126
Current database: *** NONE ***

+-----------------+
| CAST(-6 AS CHAR) |
+-----------------+
| -6               |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

What transformation mechanism?

Comment: [`ABS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs)?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html so you may need to do as `SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'; SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) -6 ;`

Comment: , if the result would otherwise have been negative, it becomes the maximum integer value:

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty  thanks